# BUILD FAILED Hybris ant npminstall

Tags: java, node.js, npm, ant, sap-commerce-cloud

everyone. I've faced the problem I am not able to execute ant npminstall command in Hybris (I also tried to execute it as sudo). {hybris.home}/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node/ shows the required version is node-v10.7.0 so I installed it on my Mac. Nothing changed. Could anyone help me fix it?

The log:

```
    [exec] gyp verb build dir attempting to create "build" dir: /Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node_modules/node-sass/build
     [exec] gyp ERR! configure error 
     [exec] gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node_modules/node-sass/build'
     [exec] gyp ERR! System Darwin 19.6.0
     [exec] gyp ERR! command "/Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node/node-v10.7.0-darwin-x64/bin/node" "/Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
     [exec] gyp ERR! cwd /Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/resources/npm/node_modules/node-sass
     [exec] gyp ERR! node -v v10.7.0
     [exec] gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
     [exec] gyp ERR! not ok 
     [exec] Build failed with error code: 1
     [exec] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules/fsevents):
     [exec] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 install: `node install`
     [exec] npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1
     [exec] 
     [exec] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
     [exec] npm ERR! errno 1
     [exec] npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
     [exec] npm ERR! Exit status 1
     [exec] npm ERR! 
     [exec] npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
     [exec] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
     [exec] 
     [exec] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
     [exec] npm ERR!     /Users/SomeUser/.npm/_logs/2021-06-05T22_10_22_301Z-debug.log

BUILD FAILED
/Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/buildcallbacks.xml:315: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/SomeUser/Work/Hybris1905/hybris/bin/modules/npm-ancillary/npmancillary/buildcallbacks.xml:115: exec returned: 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just needed to install another version of NodeJS.